# How to fold to a specific level in Vim across an entire file at once?

Tags: vim

I want to push one button in Vim and fold all the code so only code up to a specific (and variable) indent level is showing. Very useful when I want to only see method names for example and not their indented routines.

The “[Vim: Fold top level folds only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074191/vim-fold-top-level-folds-only)” question has a solution to an indent level, but it requires an environment set each time you change levels.

When my cursor is at an indent level (say level 2), I want the entire file to fold to that indent level across all methods.

Is this built into Vim somewhere? Does anyone know of a good plugin that does this?

Comment: Suggestion: look at `zm` (fold more) and `zr` (fold less); Also `zM`/`zR` for _'all the way'_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure folding to be defined by indentation:

```
:setl foldmethod=indent
```

and try the following command:

```
:let &l:foldlevel = indent('.') / &shiftwidth
```

To quickly access this command, create a mapping for it as follows:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <leader>z :let&l:fdl=indent('.')/&sw<cr>
```

Comment: for less experienced vim users, could you explain how to access that? Also, do all those three commands go into vimrc?

Answer (score 1):

Because foldnestmax doesn't apply when foldmethod is expr, I looked for something else when I came across your question.  Here is what I came up with, which doubtless can be improved:

```
function! <sid>CloseFoldOpens(opens_level)
    let lineno = 2
    let last = line("$")
    while lineno < last
        if foldclosed(lineno) != -1
            let lineno = foldclosedend(lineno) + 1
        elseif foldlevel(lineno) > foldlevel(lineno - 1)
        \ && foldlevel(lineno) == a:opens_level
            execute lineno."foldclose"
            let lineno = foldclosedend(lineno) + 1
        else
            let lineno = lineno + 1
        end
    endwhile
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> z1 :%foldclose<cr>
nnoremap <silent> z2 :call <sid>CloseFoldOpens(2)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> z3 :call <sid>CloseFoldOpens(3)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> z4 :call <sid>CloseFoldOpens(4)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> z5 :call <sid>CloseFoldOpens(5)<cr>
```

I prefer the numbered maps, but for yours based on indentation of the current line, something along these lines:

```
nnoremap <silent> z. :call <sid>CloseFoldOpens(foldlevel('.'))<cr>zv
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of a plugin, it is builtin in Vim.

'foldlevel' (or shorter 'fdl') and 'foldnestmax' ('fdn') seems to be what we were looking for. You only have to set the 'foldmethod' (or shorter 'fdm') and a 'foldnestmax' (or 'fdn') in you .vimrc file:

```
set foldmethod=indent foldlevelstart=2 foldnestmax=2
```

OR the shorter version:

```
set fdm=indent fdls=2 fdn=2
```

Then you can change the fold level with direct commands: zm or zr.